amchart map is not updating fill colors
I am trying to update the fill color of certain countries. The map shows with all the countries but the background color for some of the countries is not changing.
am5.ready(function () {

  const amcolors = [
    0x4C787E, 0x5E7D7E, 0x307D7E, 0x348781, 0x438D80, 0x4E8975, 0x1F6357, 0x306754, 0x006A4E,
    0x2E8B57, 0x1B8A6B, 0x31906E, 0x00A36C, 0x34A56F, 0x1AA260, 0x50C878, 0x3EB489, 0x3CB371,
    ... snip ...
    0xE2A76F, 0xC19A6B, 0xE6BF83, 0xDEB887, 0xD2B48C, 0xC8AD7F, 0xC2B280, 0xBCB88A, 0xC8B560
  ];

  // Create root element
  // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/getting-started/#Root_element
  let root = am5.Root.new("my-collection-map-chartdiv");

  // Set themes
  // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/concepts/themes/
  root.setThemes([
    am5themes_Animated.new(root)
  ]);

  // Create the map chart
  // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/map-chart/
  let chart = root.container.children.push(am5map.MapChart.new(root, {
    panX: "translateX",
    panY: "translateY",
    projection: am5map.geoMercator()
  }));

  // Create main polygon series for countries
  // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/map-chart/map-polygon-series/
  const polygonSeries = chart.series.push(am5map.MapPolygonSeries.new(root, {
    geoJSON: am5geodata_worldLow,
    exclude: ["AQ"]
  }));

  polygonSeries.mapPolygons.template.setAll({
    tooltipText: "{name}",
    toggleKey: "active",
    interactive: true
  });

  const seriesInfo = Object.keys(countryInfos).map((code, index) => {
    const country = countryInfos[code];
    const count = country.count ? country.count : '0';
    const fillcolor = am5.color(amcolors[index]);
    return {
      id: code,
      polygonSettings: {
        fill: fillcolor,
        tooltipHTML: `${country.name}<br/>Count: ${count}`,
      },
    };
  });


// `seriesInfo` data:
// {id: 'US', polygonSettings: {…}, geometry: {…}, geometryType: 'MultiPolygon', name: 'United States'}
// {id: 'DE', polygonSettings: {…}, geometry: {…}, geometryType: 'Polygon', name: 'Germany'}
// {id: 'AT', polygonSettings: {…}, geometry: {…}, geometryType: 'Polygon', name: 'Austria'}
// --SNIP--
// {id: 'PT', polygonSettings: {…}, geometry: {…}, geometryType: 'Polygon', name: 'Portugal'}

  console.log(seriesInfo); // <== I see all 38 items I want to color.
  polygonSeries.data.setAll(seriesInfo);

  // Make things animate on load
  chart.appear(1000, 100);

}); // end am5.ready()


I verified that the seriesInfo holds the data I want to show. Any idea why this doesn't work?
Thanks.
